# how can i call compare_exchange_weak(0,1) for an atomic variable in an array?

Tags: c++, multithreading, stdatomic, compare-and-swap

When I write down the code like this:

```
#include <atomic>
#include <array>
using namespace std;

int main() {
  array< atomic<int>, 5> a;
  a[1].compare_exchange_weak(0,1);
}
```

the compiler output:

```
no known conversion for argument 1 from 'int' to  'std::__atomic_base<int>::__int_type& {aka int &}'
```

So, can anyone explain why this failed? how can i use compare_exchange_weak in an atomic array?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The array part is irrelevant, [`compare_exchange_weak`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/atomic/atomic/compare_exchange) takes a reference as the first argument (the expected value). The literal `0` cannot be bound to a reference.

You just need a local variable:

```
int expected = 0;
a[1].compare_exchange_weak(expected, 1);
```

*This is because, if the actual value differs, compare_exchange_weak sets the expected value to the actual value.*